# Tkinter set geometry of Toplevel before displaying

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to create a `Toplevel` window that appears beside one of my other windows, but i'm having trouble figuring out how to set the location of the window **before** it is displayed. It's a simple couple lines:

```
histogram_window = Toplevel(self)
histogram_window.geometry('+%d+%d' % (self.__root.winfo_rootx() + self.winfo_x()*2, 
                          self.__root.winfo_rooty()))
histogram_window.transient(self.__root)
```

But the window will first appear, then quickly move to the location I specified. How can I simply make it appear in the location I specified?

Comment: I've done what you are trying to do (call geometry right after creating the `Toplevel()`) and have never had a problem before, any chance you can provide an MCVE?

Comment: It shouldn't be too expensive of an operation, but what if you tried calculating your position beforehand? ie, `xPos = self.__root.winfo_rootx() + self.winfo_x() * 2` & `yPos = self.__root.winfo_rooty()` and then pass those variables into `geometry()`?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that nothing is calling `update` or `update_idletasks` between the time you create the window and the time you set the position with `geometry`?  What platform is this?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the issue thanks to a reminder from Bryan Oakley, the problem was that upon the creation of the class I bound a matplotlib canvas to the screen and packed the widget, *then* tried to create a `Toplevel` window at the same time. I fixed this by calling the `update()` function for my window

```
Class some(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Toplevel(self, root)

        # created widget
        # pack widget

        self.read()

    def read(self):
        hist = Toplevel(self)
        hist.geometry(...)
        hist.update() #fixed the issue
```